# Using custom classes in Kohana 3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller, kohana-3

Hey, I'm creating a Call of duty 4 Server Watcher in Kohana 3, and I had created the basic classes for it before:

1. A static Socket class (for handling basic network commands)
2. A Cod4Socket class, (which uses the previously mentioned Socket class) that provides wrapper functions for basic commands.

What I want is to be able to use said classes inside the controllers for the website.

Where am I supposed to put the class files, where should I "include" them, and how do I use them?

**Edit:** I'm using Kohana 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where am I supposed to put the class files?

Add your class files into the application/classes/ directory with lowercase filenames.

- `Socket` should go into `application/classes/socket.php`
- `Cod4Socket` should go into `application/classes/cod4socket.php`

> Where should I "include" them, and how do I use them?

There is no need to manually include them; simply use them as if they were already included.
The Kohana autoloader will find the classes if they're in the right files.

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Info:**

Sometimes, you want to place your custom classes in a place like this

```
application/
    classes/
        controllers/
            .......
        models/
            ......
        etc/
            CustomClassFirst.php
            CustomClassSecond.php
```

You can call these classes by

```
$customClassOne = new Etc_CustomClassFirst();
```

and then redefine the class name into this

```
class Etc_CustomeClassFirst {}
```

Answer (score -3):

Did it on my own: http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2010/06/02/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-9/

You have to include the files in the **bootstrap.php** file, and then just call it normally on your controller.

Comment: If you have built the classes yourself, and only use them together with Kohana, you should add them in the Kohana-way, like Lethargy described.